# Android send data from service to BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver

How can I Send data from Service to Broadcast Receiver without using Intent because I make BroadcastReceiver listen to volume button but when I send data to it from service using intent it gives me an error I need another way?

> Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "null"

[image: My error]

Comment: `I Know How Intent work` - are you sure? A broadcast receiver is instantiated by the framework when it has a registered intent filter it is listening for - how else would you do this without an intent? Why not use a bound service instead?

Comment: you are right i make BroadcastReceiver listen to volume button but when i send data to it from service using intent it give me an error

Comment: .. and the error is ...

Answer (score 0):

To a broadcast receiver i think is not a good approach, but take a look in [bound service](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html), mainly in [AIDL](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/aidl.html?hl=pt-br).